# Trigger a New Request if a Test fails in Postman (CollectionVariable?)

Tags: javascript, api, testing, automation, postman

I'd like to trigger a new request automatically if a postman test fails.  Currently, in each request I have about 30 tests running based on what I'm expecting in the request's response.  Test Example:

```
pm.test("YES",() => {
    var yes = pm.response.json().eligibility_results.filter(obj => {
        return obj.benefit == "YES" 
    })
  pm.expect(yes[0].result).to.eql("eligible")
});
```

Now, If anything else other than the string "eligible" results for this object, the test will fail.   I'd like to write a script that tells postman if one of the 30 tests come back as a failure (not expected) a new request will automatically be initiated.

I've tried:

```
    pm.test("Check for failures", () => {
    if (pm.expect().not.eql("")) {
        (pm.sendRequest("New Request"))
    }
    else {
        pm.sendRequest(null)
        
    }
})
```

Also tried:

```
pm.test("Check for failures", () => {
    if (pm.expect(pm.response.result()).not.eql) {
        (pm.sendRequest("New Request"))
    }
    else {
        pm.sendRequest(null)
        
    }
})
```

I seem to be missing something here.  The tests are giving me a PASS in the Test Results but it isn't initiating a new separate request.  Any options?

Maybe a Post-Request if there is such a thing...

Any help greatly appreciated.